# How do I resolve the error I have in my JavaScript using imports?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to import a function from 2 different files into another one of my JavaScript files, but in the file that's importing the functions, I'm getting the error that each function is declared, but never read.

**capital.js file**:

```
function capital(string) {
  const capitalizedString =
    string.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + string.substring(1);
  return capitalizedString;
}

alert(capital("Jon"));

export default capital;
```

**addDOMContent.js file**:

```
function addDOMContent(content) {
  const node = document.createElement("h1");
  node.innerText = content;
  document.body.appendChild(node);
}
addDOMContent("Success!");

export default addDOMContent;
```

**index.js file**:

```
import capital from "./capital.js";
import addDOMContent from "./addDOMContent.js";
```

Why aren't my files being properly imported?

Comment: This error means that you are not using the imported functions in your index.js file?

Comment: Unless you omitted it, it seems like your not using the function you imported.

It's like declaring a function but not using it. Example:

const addNums = (num1, num2) => {
    return num1 + num2
};

I declared the function, right? But it's not gonna do anything unless it is called. Importing the function is like declaring it in this case, but you have not called it. To call the function, it would look like addNums(1, 2) in your code. But you have not called it, only imported it. Now that the function is correctly imported btw, you will be able to call your function in the index.js.

Comment: Ah, thank you. After posting the question, I realized that I'm missing the: export { capital, addDOMContent}; in my index.js file in order to use them in my index.html script tag.